# Warning message In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = foo) : invalid factor level, NA generated when trying to add vector to row subset

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm writing a function that attempts to add values in a single row of a data.frame in several columns at once:

```
require(stringr)

addPointsToKeyRow = function(df, keyRowNum, searchStringForPointColNames, pointsVector){
  colsWithMatchingSearchResults = str_match(colnames(df), searchStringForPointColNames)
  pointColNums = (which(!is.na(colsWithMatchingSearchResults)))
  pointsVectorCleaned = pointsVector[!is.na(pointsVector)]
  print(is.vector(pointsVectorCleaned)) #Returns TRUE
  print(is.data.frame(pointsVectorCleaned)) #Returns FALSE
  print(pointsVectorCleaned)
  if(length(pointsVectorCleaned) == length(pointColNums)){
    newDf = data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    newDf[keyRowNum, pointColNums] = as.character(pointsVectorCleaned)
    #for(i in 1:length(pointColNums)){
    #  newDf[keyRowNum,pointColNums[i]]=as.character(pointsVectorCleaned[i])
    #}
    print(newDf[keyRowNum,])
  }
}
```

When I apply the function to my data (`addPointsToKeyRow(finalDf, which(finalDf[,1]=="key"), "points_q", pointVals)`), I get the following warnings:

> In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "2") :
>     invalid factor level, NA generated

I've looked for the error on SO and other sites, and the recommendation always seems to be to make sure your data.frame has `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

I think my issue might be that when I subset the data.frame (`newDf[keyRowNum, pointColNums]`), it no longer keeps `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

Regardless of whether that's the issue or not, I'd very much welcome some help solving this weird issue. Many thanks in advance!

For the sake of an example, let's say df is:

```
df = structure(list(first = structure(c(7L, 9L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 
6L, 1L, 8L), .Label = c("autumn", "spring", "summer", "winter", 
"july", "betty", "november", "echo", "victor", "tango"), class = "factor"), 
    last = structure(c(6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 7L
    ), .Label = c("brummett1", "do", "drorbaugh", "galeno", "gerber", 
    "key", "lyons", "pecsok", "perezfranco", "swatt"), class = "factor"), 
    question1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L), .Label = c("0", "0.25", "1:02:01", "1:2 50%", "2-Jan", 
    "50%"), class = "factor"), points_q1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
    question2 = structure(c(8L, 10L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 
    4L, 9L), .Label = c("        a    |     b; A|    Aa  |  Ab; b|    ab   |  bb; the possibility that the offspring will be heterozygous is about 25%. The same goes for the homozygous recessive it is a 1:1:1:1", 
    "1/4 heterozygous for \xf1a\xee and 0 recessive for \xf1b\xee", 
    "16-Mar", "2-Jan", "3:1 25%", "4-Jan", "Male=aabb Female=AAbb Heterozygous is going to be 1/2. Homozygous is going to be 1/4.", 
    "possible offspring genotypes (each with probability of 0.25): AABb AaBb AAbb Aabb. Question is asking about probability of Aabb_ which is 0.25.", 
    "The square shows Ab Ab_ Bb Bb so 50% or 1/2.  ", "Xa Yb (father) crossed with XA Xb (mother)  = 1/2 "
    ), class = "factor"), points_q2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
    question3 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 
    1L), .Label = c("Codominance", "coheritance", "incomplete dominance", 
    "Incomplete dominance", "Incomplete dominance ", "Incomplete dominance. ", 
    "Independent Assortment"), class = "factor"), points_q3 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
    question4 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 
    4L), .Label = c("", "co-dominance", "Codominance", "Codominance ", 
    "Codominance. ", "Codominant ", "Independent Assortment? (Wrong)"
    ), class = "factor"), points_q4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
    question5 = structure(c(2L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 
    7L, 9L), .Label = c("      X   |    Y; X|  XX |  XY; x|  Xx  |  xY; the percentage will be 25 % or 1/4 the same applies to the son ", 
    "0 for daughter_ because male can only give non-colorblind X chromosome (because he's not colorblind an only has one X chromosome).  0.25 for both son and colorblind.", 
    "0.25", "25% for son and 25% for daughter", "25% for the son and 25% for the daughter ", 
    "4-Jan", "50%", "Father=XY Mother=X2Y Therefore_ by using the punnet square_ I was able to show/understand that the probability of them having a son AND him being colorblind is 1/4.", 
    "To have a son or daughter is 50/50.  To have a colorblind daughter is .25 whereas to have a colorblind son is .75 because it is carried on the X chromosome and the son is much more likely to inherit this because he has less x to work with", 
    "XcY (father) XC Xc (mother) Daughter is 1/4 son 1/4"), class = "factor"), 
    points_q5 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = "", class = "factor"), question6 = structure(c(3L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Chromatids ", 
    "Chromosomes (diploids)", "homologous chromosome pairs", 
    "Homologous chromosome pairs are being separated. ", "Homologous chromosomes ", 
    "Homologous pairs ", "homologous pairs of chromosomes", "Homologus Chromosomes ", 
    "sister chromatids ", "Sister Chromatids?"), class = "factor"), 
    points_q6 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = "", class = "factor"), question7 = structure(c(6L, 
    8L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 4L), .Label = c("", "Chromatids (haploids)", 
    "Daughter Chromosomes?", "One cell to 2", "sister chromatids", 
    "Sister chromatids", "Sister Chromatids", "Sister chromatids ", 
    "Sister chromatids within daughter cells are separating. "
    ), class = "factor"), points_q7 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
    question8 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 
    3L), .Label = c("sister chromatids", "Sister chromatids", 
    "Sister Chromatids", "Sister chromatids ", "Sister chromatids are held together by the centromeres. In prophase chromosomes become visible. During metaphase chromosomes attach to spindles. During Anaphase the chromosomes are split apart and in telophase the cells start to create cleavage.  ", 
    "sisters chromatides"), class = "factor"), points_q8 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
    question9 = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
    3L), .Label = c("prohase ", "prophase", "Prophase", "Prophase ", 
    "They condense during prophase before the rest of the phases. "
    ), class = "factor"), points_q9 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
    question10 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    4L, 2L), .Label = c("anaphase", "Anaphase", "Anaphase ", 
    "During anaphase. "), class = "factor"), points_q10 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
    question11 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L), .Label = c("During prophase. ", "Telephase ", "telophase", 
    "Telophase"), class = "factor"), points_q11 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
    question12 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    4L, 2L), .Label = c("metaphase", "Metaphase", "Metaphase ", 
    "Metaphase. "), class = "factor"), points_q12 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
    question13 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
    3L, 6L), .Label = c("centromere", "Centromere", "Centromere. ", 
    "Centromeres", "centromeres ", "Cleavage"), class = "factor"), 
    points_q13 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "", class = "factor")), .Names = c("first", 
"last", "question1", "points_q1", "question2", "points_q2", "question3", 
"points_q3", "question4", "points_q4", "question5", "points_q5", 
"question6", "points_q6", "question7", "points_q7", "question8", 
"points_q8", "question9", "points_q9", "question10", "points_q10", 
"question11", "points_q11", "question12", "points_q12", "question13", 
"points_q13"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

`which(finalDf[,1]=="key")` is 1.

`pointVals` is `c(NA, "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1")`

For clarification, I'd want the final table to look something like:

```
First    Last    question1    points_q1    question2    points_q2    etc.

key    key    0    2    "possible_offspring_genotypes..."    1    etc.
```

Comment: It is better to convert the `factor` to `character` class to avoid that error

Comment: So, how do I accomplish that, @akrun?

Comment: With `as.character()`.

Comment: So, what specifically am I applying as.character() to?

Comment: I.e., what should the syntax be?

Comment: Just to confirm are you trying to add a new row `c(NA, "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1")`  to your `df` only where it has column with "point_q" in it? Rest all should be `NA` ?

Comment: @RonakShah the rest will already have values in those rows, so I don’t want to replace them with NAs. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reduced your function based on my understanding , let me know if it gives what you want or if I have misunderstood something

```
addPointsToKeyRow = function(df, keyRowNum, searchString, pointsVector) {

    #Find columns which has searchString in it
    cols <- grepl(searchString, colnames(df))

    #Check if the columns with searchString and length of pointsVector is the same
    if (sum(cols) == length(pointsVector)) {
        #Assign the value
        df[keyRowNum,cols] <- pointsVector
    }
    #Return the updated dataframe
    df
}

#Convert all the variables in the column from factor to character
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)

#define the values to be replaced
pointVals <- c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1","1", "1")

#Call the function
df <- addPointsToKeyRow(df, 1, "points_q", pointsval)

#Check the dataframe
df
```

Comment: It seems to work, Ronak! I had to remove the NA in my vector, but that's easy enough and not germane to the issue at hand. 
I'm curious: what does df[] <- lapply(df, as.character) do?
In particular, why is are there brackets on the left hand side of the equation?

Comment: @Atticus29 `lapply(df, as.character)` converts every column to character and returns a `list`. Check by typing `lapply(df, as.character)` in the console. With those square brackets we maintain the same structure as in the original `df`. So when we do `df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)` and then we check `df` it is still a dataframe and not a list.

Comment: would it be the same thing to write `df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, as.character))`?

Comment: @Atticus29 yep. Also  `data.frame(lapply(df, as.character))` gives the same thing.